# How to limit simple form input to 50 characters

Tags: html, input

Is it possible to limit a simple form input to only 50 characters without javascript?
I have used the `max_length` attribute, however this includes blank spaces which is not what i want.
I've attempted to use `pattern` (as suggested on another post), but i can't seem to get that to work either.
Thanks

Comment: A secondary question is "why"; you'll need to validate on the server side anyway, plus 50 characters doesn't seem like the length of any common text identifier...

Comment: It feels like number 6 on the list of [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)...

Comment: I wan't to avoid the page refreshing with an error because the input has too many characters. So i'm trying to catch the error before it happens

Comment: Why is there a limit at all, though? 50 characters sounds arbitrary...

Comment: its for when a patient is booking an appointment. The input is the reason for the appointment, and i don't want a patient to write something too long for the doctor. But i don't understand why my reasoning is important? I'm asking a question, why does it matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you don't want it to include blanks.
Usually I use `max_length` including blanks and leave it to the user to trim their excess whitespace.  I'm not disagreeing, I honestly don't know what your requirement is.

If you want to allow leading and trailing whitespace, but are willing to leave it to the user to replace excess whitespace within the text to one whitespace character then this is the pattern you want:

```
<input pattern="^\s*.{0,50}\s*$">
```

Sometimes for multiline regular expressions, `\A` is used instead of `^` and `\z` is used instead of `$`, but I'm not sure HTML supports that in their regular expressions.